# Is there any custom option to lock work item for specific iteration?

Tags: tfs, devops, tfs-workitem, tfsintegrationplatform

I'm trying to lock/deny the option to open a new work item with specific iterations.

I tried to do it with a custom field with same value of iteration id and 
`<PROHIBITEDVALUES>` rule.

Then I understood that its not possible because iteration-id field load only after I press the "save" button and its too late.

There any other ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any build-in option to hide older/specific iterations in the Work Item field.

[image]

However, you can set the security for "Edit work items in this node" to deny and they will not be able to save work items with the area or iteration selected.

Besides you could also hide the iteration node(s):

- Open Project settings>Project configuration
- Select the Iteration Tab
- Select the iteration that you want to hide
- Click on Security > Add a "Deny View" permissions for the users that
  you want to hide the nodes from.

The user will not able to see the iteration in the sprint.

update:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know about the "Edit work items in this node" but it's only for Area.
And I couldn't find all the way to "Deny View" for hiding iteration.
I'm using Tfs 18 if it's supposed to be different.

Comment: @YarinDolev Have update two screenshot for your reference, please kindly review it.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help.
I tried to use permissions but its work only for area's and not for iterations.
I customize my wit for lock iteration and build a C# code for automating it.

Thanks again,
Yarin